# am only able to add maximum 5 scripts in my coded script

Tags: pine-script

I am a pro trading view user and able to add only 5 scripts in coded script.I am trading in indian market .If adding 6th script its showing compiler error.I want to add 40 scripts.How can i do that.Pls help me out.

Answer (score 1):

with Pro you only have 5 indicators per chart. In Pro+ you have 10 and in Premium you have 25. I don't think you ever can add 40, thus, irrespective of your plan.